# Selecting IDs from a MIN query that includes join

Tags: mysql

sorry about the title, very bad at titles!

I have these relevant tables:

```
Times
+--------+----------+-------------+------+---------+
| TimeID | PlayerID | MapCourseID | Mode | RunTime |
+--------+----------+-------------+------+---------+
Checkpoints
+--------------+--------+------------+---------+
| CheckpointID | TimeID | Checkpoint | RunTime |
+--------------+--------+------------+---------+
Maps
+-------+------+
| MapID | Name |
+-------+------+
MapCourses
+-----------+-------+--------+
| MapCourse | MapID | Course |
+-----------+-------+--------+
```

RunTime stores their "time" as an int

I have a query that selects the fastest times for a specific map `MapID` on all courses and all modes

```
SELECT MIN(Times.RunTime), MapCourses.Course, Times.Mode 
FROM Times 
INNER JOIN MapCourses ON MapCourses.MapCourseID=Times.MapCourseID 
INNER JOIN Players ON Players.PlayerID=Times.PlayerID
WHERE Players.Cheater=0 AND MapCourses.MapID=%d 
GROUP BY MapCourses.Course, Times.Mode;
```

Which works fine, but now I want to make another query that selects the checkpoints of the fastest times, since checkpoints are associated with a TimeID

I've tried doing something like this

```
SELECT * FROM Checkpoints 
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        MIN(Times.RunTime), 
        MapCourses.Course, 
        Times.Mode, 
        MapCourses.MapID, 
        Players.SteamID32 
    FROM 
      Times 
      INNER JOIN MapCourses ON MapCourses.MapCourseID = Times.MapCourseID 
      INNER JOIN Players ON Players.PlayerID = Times.PlayerID
    WHERE 
      Players.Cheater = 0 
      AND MapCourses.MapID = %d 
    GROUP BY 
      MapCourses.Course, 
      Times.Mode
   ) AS wrs ON Checkpoints.TimeID = wrs.TimeID
```

Also tried something like this:

```
SELECT 
  Checkpoints.RunTime, 
  Checkpoints.Checkpoint, 
  MapCourses.Course, 
  Times.Mode, 
  Times.TimeID, 
  Players.Alias 
FROM 
  Checkpoints 
  INNER JOIN Times ON Times.TimeID = Checkpoints.TimeID 
  INNER JOIN MapCourses ON MapCourses.MapCourseID = Times.MapCourseID 
  INNER JOIN Players ON Players.PlayerID = Times.PlayerID
WHERE 
  Players.Cheater = 0 
  AND MapCourses.MapID = %d 
  AND Times.RunTime = (
    SELECT 
      MIN(Times.RunTime) 
    FROM 
      Times 
    WHERE 
      Times.MapCourseID = MapCourses.MapCourseID 
      AND Mode = Times.Mode
  )
```

Neither seem to really work, any help would be great, thanks!

Basically, if i'm working on map id 50, I already have a query that gets the fastest time on map id 50 for all modes & courses, the query i'm trying to build is a query that gets the checkpoints of the fastest times for every course and mode on map id 50

Answer (score 0):

If I'm following this correctly, you want the shortest Checkpoints.TimeID for each Checkpoint in a similar format to the above?

```
SELECT MIN(Checkpoints.TimeID), MapCourses.Course, Checkpoints.Checkpoint, Times.Mode 
FROM Checkpoints
INNER JOIN Times ON Checkpoints.TimeID=Times.TimeID
INNER JOIN MapCourses ON MapCourses.MapCourseID=Times.MapCourseID 
INNER JOIN Players ON Players.PlayerID=Times.PlayerID
WHERE Players.Cheater=0 AND MapCourses.MapID=%d 
GROUP BY MapCourses.Course, Checkpoints.Checkpoint, Times.Mode;
```

Obviously not having access to your Database I can't test this, but, seems to be what you're asking?

[edit]

Ahh, so you want to keep the min times, but would like to add checkpoints into the returned values:

```
SELECT MIN(Times.RunTime), MapCourses.Course, Checkpoints.Checkpoint, Times.Mode
FROM Times 
INNER JOIN MapCourses ON MapCourses.MapCourseID=Times.MapCourseID 
INNER JOIN Players ON Players.PlayerID=Times.PlayerID
INNER JOIN Checkpoints ON Checkpoints.TimeID=Times.TimeID
WHERE Players.Cheater=0 AND MapCourses.MapID=%d 
GROUP BY MapCourses.Course, Checkpoints.Checkpoint, Times.Mode;
```

So this should return your fastest time, the map, checkpoints and then mode.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, I added some more info, but RunTime stores their "time" as an int, I want to get the checkpoints associated with the fastest times for all courses/modes on a specific map

Comment: Ah @fluffys - I've updated the above with what I think you're after (apologies, late here)

Comment: Hm, I think it's only getting the time for the fastest time on a map, which is partially right, but I also wanted it to get the fastest time for each mode & course, if that's even possible

Answer (score 0):

We could do something like this:

```
SELECT c.checkpointid
     , c.timeid
     , c.checkpoint
     , c.runtime
     , ...
  FROM ( SELECT t.mapcourseid
              , t.mode
              , MIN(r.runtime) AS min_runtime
           FROM Times r
           JOIN Players p
             ON p.playerid    = r.playerid
            AND p.cheater     = 0
           JOIN MapCourses s
             ON s.mapcourseid = t.mapcourse_id
            AND s.mapid       = ?
          GROUP
             BY t.mapcourseid
              , t.mode
       ) q
  JOIN Times t
    ON t.runtime     = q.min_runtime
   AND t.mapcourseid = q.mapcourseid
  JOIN Checkpoints c
    ON c.timeid      = t.timeid
```

The trick here is using a query as an inline view. The result returned from the query inside the parens gets returned as a resultset, which is then used like a table by the outer query. MySQL calls it a "derived table".

In the outer SELECT list, we can include references to columns from `q` and `t` as well as `c`.

Note: If there are two or more rows from `t` that match the minimumn runtime (returned by `q`), the query will return all of the matching rows.

The specification is a bit unclear. The query in this answer satisfies one particular interpretation.

Comment: This is pretty close I think, I added some more info to try help, sorry, but really, players times are stored in the RunTime column in the Times table as an int, as they pass a checkpoint during their "run" we get their time as they touch the checkpoint and it inserts a new entry in the checkpoint column.

So I want to get the checkpoint times of the fastest (world record) times for each course and mode on a specific map, that we pass in, so basically we can say the wr for map x is: 00:41:00 and their checkpoints are: 00:10:00, 00:20:00, 00:30:00 etc